# 'file' command: specifying search depth for 'search' option in /etc/magic file?

Tags: filetype

How can I specify how far/deep the '**file**' command should search in a file to locate a match on a "**search**" definition ?

I am trying to create a universal specification in "**/etc/magic**" for multi-flavoured **Prolog**, so that I could do mass-transformation of imported predicate libraries for re-targeting to my personal environment for a project.

Having reviewed a number of the "target" files, I believe I would need to **search within the first 3K characters** of a file for this to be deemed reasonably successful as an approach.

So far I've tried these 2 flavours/definition, with no success:

```
[1] 0   search/3072 [Pp][Rr][Oo][Ll][Oo][Gg]    Prolog Predicate File (ISO-Compliant Prolog), ASCII text
```

and

```
[2] 0   search  [Pp][Rr][Oo][Ll][Oo][Gg]    Prolog Predicate File (ISO-Compliant Prolog), ASCII text
```

This second one is successful but only if the pattern is found in the first line of the file.

**[Additional]** Also, I tried the following definitions:

```
[3] 0       search  :-      Prolog Predicate File (Non-Specific :-)
```

and

```
[4] 0      string  %       Prolog Predicate File (Non-Specific %), ASCII text
```

However, when I enter either of [3] or [4], below the entry for line [2], these seem to override the effectiveness of [2].  Also, for some reason, regardless of order of precedence in the file, [3] seems to "overcome" any instance that, in my view should match up with [4].

This leads me to the question: How to tell the "file" command to exit on the first match encountered in my magic file and report that?

I have also defined this initial set of other specifications to normalize the files which will be massaged to conform:

```
0   string  %%Prolog    Prolog Predicate File [Non-Specific], ASCII text 
0   string  %%gprolog   Prolog Predicate File [GNU Prolog], ASCII text 
0   string  %%swipl     Prolog Predicate File [SWI-Prolog], ASCII text 
0   string  %%yap       Prolog Predicate File [YAP Prolog], ASCII text 
0   string  %%eclipse   Prolog Predicate File [ECLiPSe], ASCII text 
0   string  %%bprolog   Prolog Predicate File [B-Prolog], ASCII text 
0   string  %%poplog    Prolog Predicate File [Poplog], ASCII text 
0   string  %%lpaprolog Prolog Predicate File [LPA Prolog], ASCII text 
0   string  %%isoprolog Prolog Predicate File [ISO-Compliant Prolog], ASCII text
```

I have created this last definition so that I may specifically tag those predicate files which I have confirmed as compliant with ISO Prolog specifications.

I do **NOT** want to use the "shebang" (i.e. #!/bin/gprolog) notation for first line auto-detection for execution.

**[Additional]** I just discovered a gotcha.  How can I configure the installation to ensure any standard/builtin "shebang" notation is evaluated before my customized /etc/magic entries, but at the same time have my /etc/magic definitions be evaluated before any other magic sequences?

Guidance on search depth specification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think SuperUser might not be the best place for this, it's usually a bit ... lower level. I'd delete this question, and ask it in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) or maybe [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) - better chances to get a meaningful answer, methinks :-)

Comment: I was directed here by stack overflow.  I guess I'll try the Unix one next.  Thank you.

Comment: You were what again from where??? There are 37,755 postings in the entire StackExchange mentioning keyword "prolog". Out of those 41 in SuperUser, 26 in Unix&Linux - and in StackOverflow  34,860... and someone in SO sends you to SU??? I think someone might have even less clue than I do what you're talking about - at least I recognized the subject and the bloody compiler :-D

Comment: This is NOT a Prolog issue.  This is a "file" command and "magic" file issue.  I'm being bounced around because everybody is being thrown off by the mention of Prolog !!!  original post was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179021/file-command-specifying-search-depth-for-search-option-in-magic-file

Comment: Right... and the next one is a bumbling idiot who fat-fingers ls so can't find /etc/magic and misunderstands the question entirely... I totally understand the frustration. My honest apology! Also thanks, I just now learned something new :-)